# Java cannot find constructor

Tags: java

Like most new programmers I have a small but significant issue that i cannot figure out. 
My program will not pull my constructor. I have tried quite a few different ways and cant seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Error
EmployeeTest.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor Employee()
location: class Employee
    Employee x = new Employee();
                 ^
EmployeeTest.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor Employee()
location: class Employee
    Employee y = new Employee();
```

```
public class Employee
{
private double salaryValue; // variable that stores monthlySalary
private String firstName; // instance variable that stores first name
private String lastName; // variable that stores last name

 public Employee( String firstNameParameter , String lastNameParameter ,  double          salaryValueParameter )
{

    if ( salaryValueParameter < 0.0 ) // validate monthlySalary > 0.0
    salaryValue = 0.0; // if not salary is intitalized to default

    else 

      firstName = firstNameParameter;
      lastName = lastNameParameter;
      salaryValue = salaryValueParameter;
}  

 public class EmployeeTest 
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{   
String temp;
Double temp2;
Double temp3;

Employee x = new Employee();
Employee y = new Employee();
```

Comment: By the way, `double` is often *not* the best data type to model currency quantities due to the rounding errors that can accumulate over time.

Answer (score 10):

Because you've added a constructor that takes 3 arguments, the `Employee` class no longer has a default constructor - one which takes no arguments. So you can't do this:

```
Employee x = new Employee();
```

and you must include 3 arguments:

```
Employee x = new Employee("firstname", "lastname", 123.45);
```

If you want to instantiate an `Employee` without supplying any parameters, you must add a no-argument constructor:

```
public Employee() {
}
```

You can read more about default constructors in [section 8.8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) of the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/).

Answer (score 3):

You're calling a constructor without any parameters:

```
new Employee()
```

This causes Java to look for this default constructor in your class:

```
public Employee() {}
```

Which it can't find because you have a custom constructor with parameters, hence the error. Your `Employee` class only has this constructor:

```
public Employee(String, String, double) {}
```

You should either pass parameters to the constructors in your `new` statements, or declare that default parameter-less constructor explicitly and implement it (as an overload of your other constructor, perhaps to pass in default values or something).

Answer (score 2):

By default, a class has a no-arg constructor. I.e.

```
 public Employee()
```

If you later and go add your own constructor.. i.e.

```
 public Employee( String name )
```

Then the listed ones are the only ones you can use.

If you still want to call the default one, add it back in.

```
public Employee()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a default public constructor:

```
public void Employee();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your default constructor. When you implement a custom one, the default is lost

```
public class Employee{
   public Employee(){}
...
}
```

[Here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2000/jw-1013-constructors.html) is a short article on constructors

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor defines 
    String firstNameParameter , String lastNameParameter ,  double          salaryValueParameter

as parameters.  When you call
    Employee x = new Employee();
you are calling a non-existant constructor.  Try the following instead:

```
Employee x = new Employee('David', 'Jones', 50000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to create a new class with an empty constructor, but the only constructor you have declared is one requiring parameters.  You should probably try something like:

```
Employee x = new Employee("Bob", "Jones", "100.0");
```

Or, declare a default constructor:

```
public Employee() {
    //do cool stuff here
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You provide only a constructor with three arguments, but you try to call a constructor without arguments. Such a constructur is included automatically by the compiler but *only* if your class has no other constructors.

So you have two options:

- Include another constructor without arguments
- call the constructor with the right number and types of arguments