# Java: cannot find symbol (constructor)

Tags: java, constructor, compiler-errors

newbie doing Java homework here. I have one class named Album which contains the following constructors:

```
public class Album {

    private String title;
    private String artist;
    private String genre;
    private Song favoriteTrack;
    private int trackNumber;
    private static int numAlbums;

    //Constructors
    public Album(String title, Song favoriteTrack, int trackNumber) {
        this.title = title;
        this.favoriteTrack = favoriteTrack;
        this.trackNumber = trackNumber;
        artist = favoriteTrack.getArtist();
        genre = favoriteTrack.getGenre();
        numAlbums++;
    }

    public Album(String title, Song favoriteTrack) {
        this(title, favoriteTrack, 1);
    }
...}
```

And then I have a second class MusicCollection which instantiates the Album class thrice, within its main method...

```
public static void main (String[] args) {...

    Album album1 = new Album("Debut", "Venus as a Boy", 3);
    Album album2 = new Album("Homework", "Around the World", 7);
    Album album3 = new Album("Ghost in the Machine", "Invisible Sun", 3);
    ...}
```

However, when I attempt to compile MusicCollection.java, I get the error:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol : constructor Album(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int)
location : class Album
```

for each time I try to call the constructor.
The classes Album and MusicCollection ARE in the same directory, and Album.java compiles.
I imagine I'm doing something silly, but I can't figure this out.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Asking for homework help is fine, but remember to include the homework tag.

Comment: Alrighty, I will remember that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java cannot find constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858538/java-cannot-find-constructor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument of the constructor you defined is `Song`, not `String`, but in your main, you try to instantiate it with a `String` as a second argument.

Comment: Ahh. Figured it was something silly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a `String` to the second argument of the `Album` constructor, when you have declared that it should receive an instance of `Song`.

Answer (score 1):

What Binyamin said! If you have a song class you need to say something like `new Album("Debut", new Song("venus as a boy"), 3);` depending on how your Song class works, if not, change song to a string type

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to instantiate Album with 2 strings rather than a string and some class `Song`, maybe you should change the constructor to

```
public Album(String title, String favoriteTrack, int trackNumber) {
    this.title = title;
    this.favoriteTrack = favoriteTrack;
    this.trackNumber = trackNumber;
    artist = favoriteTrack.getArtist();
    genre = favoriteTrack.getGenre();
    numAlbums++;
}
```

or do this:

```
new Album("Debut", new Song("Venus as a boy"), 3);
```

or however Song is created.