# Constructor - cannot find symbol

Tags: java, class, inheritance, constructor

I am trying to compile a program, which has a subclass `DramaticGame`, of Game. The subclass contains the following:

```
public class DramaticGame extends Game
{
  public DramaticGame(String machineName, int machineSize, String rackName, int rackSize)
  {
    super.makeMachine(machineName, machineSize);
    super.makeRack(rackName, rackSize);
  }
}
```

> DramaticGame.java:5: cannot find symbol
>
> symbol  : constructor Game()
>
> location: class Game
>
> {
>
> ^

It says it cannot find the "{" symbol in Game, but i am not sure how to fix this.

```
public Game(String paramString1, int paramInt1, String paramString2, int paramInt2)
{
  this.machine = makeMachine(paramString1, paramInt1);
  this.rack = makeRack(paramString2, paramInt2);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java cannot find constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858538/java-cannot-find-constructor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your superclass is missing default constructor which is invoked implicitly if you do not
issue

```
super(eventual params);
```

as first statement in your constructor.

Comment: so what would my default constructor be? I have added the constructor in the superclass to the end of my original post above. Thanks

Comment: But you are not calling it from the subclass. So Java will invoke the default constructor `Game()` which does not exist. In you `DefaultGame()` constructor you should insert a call to it like this for example `super(machineName,machineSize,rackName,rackSize)` and your error will then disappear (exactly as the answer above suggests to do).

Answer (score 0):

No, what it can't find is a default constructor.

The compiler will create a no-argument default constructor if you don't supply any constructors.

But the moment you write one you're on your own.

I'd advise that you write one that calls the one you've already written with default arguments:

```
public class DramaticGame extends Game
{
  public DramaticGame() {
      this("default-machine-name", 1024, "default-rack-name", 10); 
  }

  public DramaticGame(String machineName, int machineSize, String rackName, int rackSize)
  {
    super.makeMachine(machineName, machineSize);
    super.makeRack(rackName, rackSize);
  }
}
```

I'd also wonder if your Game constructor should take rack name and size. The fact that those are members of the Game class suggests to me that they should be set in the Game constructor.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the default constructor, if this is the constructor used in the superclass:

Comment: Yes; you didn't write one.  If the Game class has one, you should call it.

Comment: I have added it to the end of my original post. Thanks

Comment: I'd prefer that you vote up and accept the answer to your thanks.  Good for me, good for you.